# Run 120v gear on batteries? Lightweight options even possible?

Tags: field-recording, portable-recorder, location-recording

So Im looking to upgrade my audio interface and found the RME UFX which has some great field recording capabilities aside from the lack of battery powered operation. I also want to upgrade my portable recording gear so i would love to kill 2 birds here.

I know about using car batteries and inverters but those are heavy.

I dont have high hopes for finding a solution but thought i would ask

Answer (score 1):

First off, your gear may not actually run on 120 volts. Virtually all of the devices we use have step down transformers...what we commonly refer to as power supplies. Look at any external power brick, and it will tell you what it outputs to the device that it powers. The UFX has a built in power supply, though. So, it's not like you can bypass it without having someone make some serious modifications to the gear. That's not to say it's impossible, but it goes way beyond my knowledge as to how it could be done.

As far as field power solutions that don't require modding, I don't really know.  Maybe [Stuart Cody](http://www.automatedmedia.com/index.html) can give you some ideas. He specializes in batteries for extreme conditions film-making. It may be something out of his expertise as well, but he's a far better starting point than I am.